# Saving the react native bundle when integrating in existing android application

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I have an android application and react native application, i had integrated my react app into existing android app.
Now i have screens like

Native Screen 1 ---> OnClick Btn ---> React Native Bundle. Now my react native bundle is loaded.

Now if press back from React native Bundle i navigate back to native screen. Now if i again click the btn and navigate to react native bundles, in this case my entire bundle of react native will be loaded again, so i want to prevent it. I want if i have loaded one bundle in react native, i want to save its instance so that next time if i move to that bundle it will be used from there only without loading it again.